# Expert advice needed on selection of automation tool

Tags: automated-testing

I'm posting here to seek a professional advice on choosing an automation tool for a desktop application. It's developed in C# and I need to test the UI part. Initially, I started using "coded test UI" and it worked well. Recently, while referring to some help on the tool on Microsoft site, I came across this

> "Coded UI Test for automated UI-driven functional testing is
>   deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where Coded UI Test
>   will be available. We recommend using Selenium for testing web apps
>   and Appium with WinAppDriver for testing desktop and UWP apps."

I have no idea how to use Appium and how efficient it would be to record the tests and perform integration testing.

Question

1. Shall I continue exploring coded test UI OR
2. I shall switch to Appium? Any pointers which can provide through knowledge for beginners to start using this tool?

Answer (score 1):

Appium basically works the same way as Selenium and testing web applications.

The main difference for you will be to use `WindowsElement` instead of `WebElement`.

There are great examples how to start with this on [WinAppDriver github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver). I would suggest starting there with writing easy tests for Windows Calculator.

In my work i'm using [Appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/) with WinAppDriver and [SpecFlow](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow) for writing BDD test cases. Underneath I'm writing glue code using C# & Page Object Pattern architecture. But I think you can use JavaScript or other languages if you prefer to.